# Is this bat with shiny substance consistent with pine tar legal?

Tags: rules, baseball, equipment

According to the [MLB Rules](http://mlb.mlb.com/documents/0/4/0/224919040/2017_Official_Baseball_Rules_dbt69t59.pdf), 3.02(c):

> The bat handle, for not more than 18 inches from its end, may be
>   covered or treated with any material or substance to improve the grip.
>   Any such material or substance that extends past the 18- inch
>   limitation shall cause the bat to be removed from the game.

Now, during tonight's World Series game, LA Dodgers player Turner was using the bat below. Clearly, you can see a shiny substance on the bat, which looks consistent with pine tar. Would this not be an illegal bat according to the rules?

[image: Bat]

Comment: He put it on the wrong end.